# How to group GLTF element and drag and drop in 3js

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Single GLTF element i can drag and drop. but group of element i can't drag. I am using following code

```js
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
                loader.load( 'W3030/W3030.gltf', ( gltf ) => {

                    gltf.scene.traverse( function( child ) {
                        if(child.type === "Group")
                        {
                            newObject = true;
                            GLTFobjects.push(child);
                        }
                        if ( child.isMesh ) {
                            child.receiveShadow = true;
                            child.castShadow = true;
                            child.material.transparent = true;
                            child.material.opacity = 1;
                        }

                    });
                     scene.add(GLTFobjects);
                     gltf.scene.scale.set(1, 1, 1);

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Thanks for your support. Now i drag.
Use following code to drag multi mesh GLTF. It is Work for me.

```
 var dragobjects =[];
 //add following code in init function
 var gltfobject = addGLTFObjectIntoScene();
 scene.add(gltfobject);

dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(dragobjects, camera, renderer.domElement);
dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, false);
dragControls.addEventListener('drag', onDrag , false);
dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', onDragEnd, false);
```

//end init function code
//add following function after or before init function

```
 function drawBox(objectwidth,objectheight,objectdepth){
 var geometry, material, box;
 geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(objectwidth,objectheight,objectdepth);
 material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00, transparent: true, opacity: 0,depthTest:false});
 box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 dragobjects.push(box);
 box.position.set(0, 0, 0);
 return box;
};  
function addGLTFObjectIntoScene(){ 
 group = new THREE.Group();
 var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
 loader.load( 'W1230/W1230.gltf', ( gltf ) => {
    mesh = gltf.scene;
    mesh.scale.set( 30, 30, 30);
    var gltfbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh );
    var objectwidth = Math.floor(gltfbox.getSize().x);
    var objectheight = Math.floor(gltfbox.getSize().y);
    var objectdepth = Math.floor(gltfbox.getSize().z);
    objectwidth = objectwidth + parseInt(2);
    objectheight = objectheight + parseInt(2);
    objectdepth  = objectdepth + parseInt(1);
    mesh.position.set(0, -objectheight/2, 0);
    box  = drawBox(objectwidth,objectheight,objectdepth); 
    group.add(box);
    group.name = "quadrant";
    console.log(mesh);
    box.add( mesh);
 });
 return group;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid instances of `Group` are not supported by `DragControls` since there is no `Group.raycast()` method.

You can implement a workaround by replacing groups with invisible meshes. However, instead of setting `Object3D.visible` to `false`, you do this for `Material.visible`. Otherwise the raycasting logic will not perform the intersection test. It's then necessary to use a geometry that is large enough to enclose the respective children.

`three.js R110`

Comment: var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'W3030/W3030.gltf', ( gltf ) => {
     this.scene.add( gltf.scene );
      gltf.scene.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
     // gltf.scene.position.set(400,400,400)
     gltf.scene.traverse( function( object ) {
      if ( object.isMesh ) objects.push( object );
      if ( object.isMesh ) objects.castShadow = true;
     } );

    });

Comment: i refer your following comment and help me. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-drag-correctly-the-obj-file/7599

Comment: Can you see this? https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-scene-traverse-get-typeerror-cannot-read-property-traverse-of-undefined/6151/7?u=althaf_khan